# Getting all the items in an array except one of my choice

Tags: c#, arrays

Im trying to make a bot that will recognize different commands. For example, one command would be `" add 'x text' "` ,  as a TODO  list. I have set up the recognition of the command by splitting the input to an array, and then getting `array[0]`, or else the first word which will always be the command. Now, I would like to somehow save the other items in the sentence that was split except from the keyword (AKA [0] ) , meaning [1] [2] [3] etc. What is one way of getting all the items besides the [0] one ? I've tried to skip it by doing: `myarray.Skip(x)`  , but I failed at making it work. Thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that reproduces your issue. Some example input and output will really help. It could be as easy as `var result = source.Where(condition)`.

Comment: have a look at the LINQ 'Where' method, you can either provide a lambda that works on the actual item, or a combination of the item and index.

Comment: Something like string.Join(" ", array.Skip(1).ToArray())? But it might be better to use a regex to split your command in two parts.

Answer (score 2):

As @[L-Three](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466192/l-three) has suggested, you can use `string.Join(" ", myarray.Skip(1).ToArray())` to get the rest of the string without the first word.

Your example with `myarray.Skip(x)` didn't work because `Skip(x)` is a Linq function and thus it is a [deferred execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669162.aspx) operation. It means that you just described what you need to do, but the action isn't executed yet. A call to '`.ToArray()`', '`.ToList()`' for example (as L-Three has used in his solution) will execute the action.

It is important to note that there are other ways to achieve what you want (like using Regex - as it is already suggested in the comments) which might be safer than the method that you are using now.

Comment: I used this method but I got an error, in the string.Join part, saying "Member  'string.Join(string, params string[])' , cannot be accessed with an instance referance; Qualify it with a type name instead" . This is the code I tried         `     switch (keyword[0].ToLower())
            {

                case "add":

                   foreach (string word in keyword)  // Keyword being the array 
                    {
                        word.Join(" ", keyword.Skip(1).ToArray());

                    }
                    break;

            } '

Comment: @VaggelisD please use 'string'.Join or 'String'.Join. This is a static method and you need to reference it from the class and not from the instance. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: @VaggelisD if 'myarray' is your array variable name, then just copy this to your code: 'String restOfString = string.Join(" ", myarray.Skip(1).ToArray());'